# How to determine The Banner Ad has been clicked using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have PHP site and i want add banner ads for ( cost per click )
but when the banner ads showing in my site
Thats calculation the impressions and the clicks

```
$adsetting_temp=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM adsetting"));
$doing_spots=1;

while($adsetting_temp[ppcban_spot] >= $doing_spots) {
$ppcbanads=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ads where ppcban='1' and expired='0' and active='0'  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;"));
$displayppcbanad="<a href='$ppcbanads[link]' target='_blank' ><img src='$ppcbanads[info]'width='468' height='60'></a>";

mysql_query("update ads set clicksdone=clicksdone+1, active='1' where id=$ppcbanads[id]");

if ($ppcbanads[clicksdone]+1 >= $ppcbanads[clicksbought]) { mysql_query("update ads set expired=1 where id=$ppcbanads[id]");}

if ($ppcbanads[id] == '') {$displayppcbanad="<a href='$adsetting_temp[defaultlink]' target='_blank'><img src='$adsetting_temp[defaultppcban]' width='468' height='60'></a>";}

$template->assign("ppcbanad$doing_spots",$displayppcbanad);

$doing_spots++;}
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: it is ok now ??? because i am not programmer and  i dont know what you mean, thanx

Comment: 1. If you're not a programmer, you should hire a freelancer or start learning from the ground up. You are making changes to your code that you do not know what actually is happening. 2. The edit you made to your question will **break** your code. Please consider my response to #1.